# linux permission access chain

Tags: linux, file-permissions

I am looking for the full chain that is followed when accessing a file (in Linux).  There are numerous sources that just talk about the standard set of UNIX permissions, sometimes including ACL's or SELinux, but not in any depth.

The permissions that I am aware of:

- Standard UNIX permissions: User -> Group -> Other
- ACL

  - User -> User of explicit ACL -> Group -> Group of explicit ACL -> Other
- SELinux
- Attributes (list with lsattr)
- Extended attributes (list with getfattr)
- File system mount options

So how do I figure out the trail that is used to check if a user has permission on a file through all those sets?

Comment: Note that the list of possible permission types is also dependent on the file system in use, and in some cases mount options, etc.

Comment: I suggest sacrificing a Windows XP machine at midnight on the 1st of May (if you are in the US) or 5th of January elsewhere in the world, and beseeching the demons of code to answer your question.

Comment: Given that the filesystem *might* be something unconventional (including user space fuser mounts, for example), there could be utterly arbitrary other constraints.  While simply opening something with a specific mode is the most straightforward way to check to see if one *has* the desired access, that doesn't answer you question about the full chain.  But really, we can't answer that, because dynamically mounted filesystems mean the answer can change.  However, see do_dentry_open in https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/fs/open.c